# I can't create a table and populate with SQLALchemy and Docker

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, dockerfile

that is the class main.py

```
import os
from db_connector import DbConnector
import sqlalchemy as sa

# Definire il modello della tabella
Base = sa.declarative_base()
class GroceryItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(50))
    qty = sa.Column(sa.Integer)#quantity

# Connessione al database
db_url = os.getenv('DB_URL')
db = DbConnector(db_url)
items_table = db.get_table_from_name("items")

def add_grocery_item(item_name, item_qty):
 with db.engine.connect() as connection:
        grocery_item = GroceryItem(name=item_name, qty=item_qty)
        connection.execute(items_table.insert().values(name=item_name, qty=item_qty))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    add_grocery_item("zucchine", 4)
    add_grocery_item("pomodoro", 24)
    add_grocery_item("zucchine", 4)
    add_grocery_item("pomodoro", 24)
```

thi is the db_connector class

```
import sqlalchemy as sa

class DbConnector:
    #inizializza l'istanza DbConnector
    def __init__(self, db_url):
        self.db_url = db_url
        self.engine = sa.create_engine(db_url)
        self.metadata = sa.MetaData(bind=self.engine)
        
    #Recupera una tabella con il nome specificato  
    def get_table_from_name(self, table_name):
        return sa.Table(table_name, self.metadata, autoload=True)
    
    #Esegue una query SQL generica sul database
    def execute_statement(self, statement):
        with self.engine.connect() as connection:
            return connection.execute(statement)
```

And there is the dockercompose-file

```
version: "3"

services:
  backend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ./src:/home/ai/src
    container_name: backend-container
    enviroment:
        DB_URL: "postgresql://postgres:password@db:5432/lista_spesa"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
    
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres -d lista_spesa"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 10
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: lista_spesa
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    container_name: db-container

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

the url of yhe docker-cp,pose file i think is correct , because when i do thi scommand:
build step: docker compose build
run: docker compose up -d
i have no type of error

when i run the main.py this is the error
line 846, in make_url
raise exc.ArgumentError(
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Expected string or URL object, got None

Comment: in your compose file, `DB_URL` is set for the `db` service, I think you must set that for `backend`?

Comment: With your modification , when i do the command "docker compose build"
show this error: "yaml: line 14: did not find expected key"

Comment: yes of course .

Comment: like this man ?

Comment: no man , this things still don't working , i think the problem is not in the docker-compose

Comment: when i do "cdocker compose build"
show this type of error: "panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[string]interface {}, not string"